# "&" character in url

Tags: sql-injection, injection, url-redirection, url

I think I found a bug in my website but don't know how dangerous it is.

My website will redirect you to a warning page whenever you click on a link that is pasted in the comments section.

The url of the warning page consists of

https://example.com/redirect?signature=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&url=http%3A%2F%google.com%2F

If you try to modify the signature code or the url it will prompt you with "Something went wrong, please try again later".

Now if you add an "&" after the signature nothing will happen! e.g.:

https://example.com/redirect?signature=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&NothingHappend!&url=http%3A%2F%google.com%2F

Is this behavior dangerous or exploitable by anyway?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Without seeing the code that consumes the input from the querystring, it's impossible to say whether this condition is exploitable. Any code that deals with user input (querystring or otherwise) needs to be very careful with what it does with it.

Comment: Why do you need the signature thing, anyway? What would an exploit of this page look like?

Answer (score 2):

The ampersand character is used to separate arguments supplied to the url when multiple argments are used. In your first example the script receives the following arguments

```
signature=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
url=http%3A%2F%google.com%2F
```

In your second example the script receives the following arguments:

```
signature=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
NothingHappend!=
url=http%3A%2F%google.com%2F
```

As you can see you have added an additional argument, however as the other arguments haven't changed and your script (probably) doesn't use the "NothingHappened" argument it doesn't affect the script in any way.

Comment: Why would the existence of an additional qs param (that he presumably doesn't use) cause his page behavior to change?

Comment: Perhaps I misread, based on his description it seems to me that he thinks changing the signature with a & doesn't cause the invalid signature error and he's wondering why.

Comment: I think the parser may be tokenizing parameters by splitting on `?/&`, then on `=`. Which means you'll end up with two NameValue Pairs: (1) `signature` set to `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` and (2) `NothingHappend!&url` set to `http%3A%2F%google.com%2F`.

Comment: I'm wrong; a new `&` appears to restart the parser. I'd like to see the code that operates on the QS args.

Comment: I thought it might be interesting for you guys to know that if you put in the encoded "&" which is "%26" it will prompt me with "Something went wrong, please try again later"

Comment: Have you consider HPP (HTTP Parameter Pollution)? What happens if you do /?signature=abc&signature=def

Comment: Shouldn't that be `NothingHappend!=` instead of `&NothingHappend!=`?

Comment: Yes @Mico, because % is not & the web server parses it differently. This is expected behaviour :)

Answer (score 0):

If the `signature` parameter is based on user input, it may be possible for a user to insert an `&` in it and break this functionality. I don't see how this could be exploited, however the best practice is to sanitize the value of parameters affected by user input.